# Get Use object with his relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a user model that have role_id and grade_it.

I would like to be able to select a user row with the role name and grade name inside.

```
class User extends Model{
public function grade()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Grade');
}

public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
 }
```

What is the better way to get it???

I wouldn't like to do:

```
User::where('condition')
      ->join('grade')
      ->join('role')
      ->select('fields')
      ->get();
```

Because I think there is a better way with Eloquent, isnt't it?

Comment: How about eager loading?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Laravel Eager Loading. Try this:

```
User::where('condition') ->with(['grade', 'role'])->select('fields') ->get();
```